# WD: UDMA CRC Errors and Reallocated Sector

Tags: hard-drive

I got a WD Caviar Black 1TB (WD1001FALS) and according to SMART, I got:

- one "Reallocated Sector"
- one "Reallocated Event"
- 26 UDMA CRC Errors

in my drive but it's a "Pass" for the "SMART overall-health self assessment test". I think it's because of these, I'm having problems with Grub, and thus can't boot into any OS at all. Are these problems serious?

According to "Warranty Services", my drive is still "In Limited Warranty". Would I be eligible for a replacement?

FYI: I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Reallocated Sectors" are instances where the drive found a bad area on the disk, and remapped the sector occupying that space to one from the spare area - today's hard drives keep a number of "spare sectors" in reserve.

As "reallocated" means the drive has in effect resolved the error, this is not likely to be the cause of your GRUB issues.

What would cause errors are the "Uncorrectable Sector Count" or similar - this means the drive could not repair the error found.  These, as opposed to "Reallocated" mean it cannot retrieve the data from that block.

I am not sure what a "normal" value is for your specific drive and if there is a need to panic over one reallocated sector.  I would watch the value and if more reallocations occur, then I would be concerned.  Would avoid warranty unless you really need it as you may get a refurbished drive.

Comment: Also, constant backups.  Regardless of the status of the drive, you should have a backup of everything on them in case of worst-case-scenario failures.